# Addactionlistener doesnot take parameter

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Concentration extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttons[][]=new JButton[4][4];
    int i,j,n;      

    public Concentration() {            
        super ("Concentration");    
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
        panel.setSize(400, 400);            
        for( i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for (j=0; j<buttons[i].length;j++){ 
                n=i*buttons.length+buttons[i].length;
                buttons[i][j]=new JButton();                    
                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);       
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
        buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                 getClass().getResource("/images/2.jpg")));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Concentration();
    }    
}
```

This is my code. I am making memory game. I want to make that, each time clicked a button, that button shows image but

```
 buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
```

in that, methot can not take i and j and doesnot show any image.

But for example when i do

```
 buttons[2][2].addActionListener(this);
```

it shows only in 2x2 . image. What can i do to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Inside the ActionListener, iterate through the button array to see which JButton in the array matches the button that was pressed, obtained by calling `e.getSource()`
- Give your JButtons actionCommand Strings that correspond to i and j
- Create a separate ActionListener implementing class that has i and j fields that can be set via a constructor, and give each button a unique ActionListener with i and j set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
        JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if(pressedButton.getIcon() == null){
            pressedButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/2.jpg")));
        } else {
            pressedButton.setIcon(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Direct form [EventObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) javadoc:

> `public Object getSource()`
>
> The object on which the Event initially occurred.
>
> Returns:
>       The object on which the Event initially occurred.

This means there's no need to know the array indexes of pressed button as it could be known through `getSource()` method.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I have +1 (think is yours, thank you) but another -1 that I'd like to know why.

Comment: You've got one 1+ from me. It's good to show the getSource() method in action with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see then. Thanks guys! :) @nIcEcOw yes, I'll keep smiling :-)